# how to configure aws lambda to be able to access services on the emr master node?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-emr, system-administration

My AWS Lambda function can't access the hive server running on the master node.  It times out -- the same behavior as if you try to access the node from a non white-listed IP.  Obviously adding the Lambda function as a whitelisted IP is a non starter.

How do I configure AWS Lambda so that it can access services on the EMR master node?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Make your lambda run in private subnets of the same VPC as that of your EMR cluster.

In the EMR security group, add an inbound rule with the port that needs to be accessed with the lambda security group as source security group id. This will allow all lambda requests.

See if this helps !!

Comment: YOU DA REAL MVP

Comment: Thank you !! Please award the bounty to the answer !!